# match and replace section in PNG file

Tags: shell, imagemagick, png

is it possible to use command line program to replace a section within PNG when it match sample picture?

like:

When weather report in PNG match the image of "sun.png", replace that specific section on weather-report.png to sun.png while leave other content in weather-report.png untouched.
[image]

if cloud image match right bottom "Selection_003.png" in "Hong_Kong.png", then replace that specific section with "Selection_004.png"

Comment: Sounds like you're talking about *template matching* - see this [OpenCV template matching tutorial](http://docs.opencv.org/3.2.0/de/da9/tutorial_template_matching.html)

Comment: I added picture example, please have a look.

Comment: Did you look at the tutorial I linked? anyhow this seems to be a question about image processing, not Unix/Linux

Comment: Placing a high resolution image into a TTY screenshot might only end up looking "kinda stupid", after all the hard work you put into making it work. :) May I suggest the following idea: scrape the original text, and transform it to a webpage: HTML+CSS+PNG/SVG images.  Better yet, if that weather system has some sort of API (which returns structured data: JSON, XML, CSV, whatever ..) use that instead of TTY screen scraping.